# Best Audio interface for TR808 and JU-06?

Tags: audio

I am currently using an old soundcraft folio mixer and don't think it's working properly anymore. So i need a new Audio Interface. I want to connect a Roland TR 808 Drum machine and a Roland Boutique JU-06. Can anyone recommend a suitable audio interface for these two instruments to connect. Also how would they connect ? Most reviews of interfaces are aimed at condenser mics, phantom power and guitar connections. Any information would be most helpful as i'm new to interfaces and connections always seem to baffle me. Thanks for taking the time to read this - Simon.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for your information, so helpful to me. I really did'nt know i could use the JU-06 like that. Much appreciated thanks again - Simon.

Comment: Soulbeatrunner - if Radiosac helped you, please just click on the upvote next to his post, or the "accept answer" check mark. Posts are just for questions or answers, not for saying thanks. (All this is covered in our [about] page)

Answer (score 1):

Both of those instruments output line level signals, so really any interface will work just fine.  Just because an interface features phantom power or high impedance guitar inputs only means you can use it for other purposes, not specifically those types of inputs only.
As an aside, you don't necessarily need another interface, the Ju-06 IS an interface.  Audio and MIDI are routed through the USB port.  So you could run the output of the 808 into the input of the Ju-06 and it will automatically come out the output of the Ju-06.